# Проблема с Денвер...

Tags: php, denwer, mysql

В phpMyAdmin пишет, что Расширение mcrypt не найдено. Пожалуйста, проверьте ваши настройки PHP.
Почитал, все пишут, что надо раскомментировать строку extension=php_mcrypt.dll в php.ini но вот только это не помогает. Что нужно сделать, мне эта хрень мешает установить CMS Magento(((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, так самой библиотеки - файла **php_mcrypt.dll** - нет в наборе. [Скачайте из инета](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-FCjMFmnZuxX0lyaHMzTW1iTzQ) и киньте в папочку \usr\local\php5\ext

Answer (score 1):

Установи php дополнения под denwer типо php5 и тд

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в папке php, создать папку tmp, если не помогает, то в файле php.ini закоментировать строку "session.save_path = "C:/php/tmp" ".